# Динамическое программирование с++

Tags: c++

Как проверить, можно ли из пяти заданных цифр операциями : `+`, `-`, `*` сделать число 23?

Comment: если цифр 5, то можно сделать примерно за 5! * 4^4 и без ДП.

Comment: можно узнать как именно ?

Comment: полным перебором. Вы попробуйте, если что-то не понятно будет, спрашивайте, показывайте код, поможем. А за кого-то тут не делают задания.

Comment: Вообще-то у Кнута в 4 томе проскакивало, что такие задачи решаются перебором. Откровенно говоря, динамическое программирование - не мой конек, я в нем слаб, так что тут мое мнение недорого стоит... но не представляю, как его можно применить к данной задаче.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто (в теории). Представьте, что задача уже решена для 4-х цифр из 5-ти. То есть вы знаете все возможные числа, которые только и можно получить с 4-мя цифрами и указанными операциями. Теперь нужно "приделать" 5-ю цифру ко всем этим комбинациям со всеми возможными операциями. Соответственно, чтобы решить задачу с четырьмя цифрами, нужно решить сначала с тремя... и т. д. до одной цифры. С одной цифрой всё тривиально (хотя, тут нужно смотреть, разрешён ли унарный минус).

Данная стратегия, как может показаться, мало чем отличается от полного перебора, но всё-такие она проще. Полный перебор даёт гиперэкспоненциальную сложность, а данный метод только экспоненциальную. Проблема только в том, как это грамотно запрограммировать, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Как с одной цифрой и унарным минусом получить число `23`?

Comment: а вы учитываете знак умножить? он влияет на порядок выполнения операций и следовательно мы не можем из значения на предыдущем шаге получать значение на следующем. Точнее можем, но это лишний параметр (тогда будут параметры ДП: [маска, значение, значение последнего блока]) и для 5 элементов реализовывать это я лично смысла не вижу. Вот если бы их 10-15 было :)

Comment: Никак. Я говорю о том, что если унарный минус разрешён, то вместо 5 стартовых вариантов будет 10. Это усложняет задачу.

Comment: @Zealint да не особо, всего в 2 раза больше вариантов, это не так и страшно.

Comment: @pavel, обратите внимание, что я не говорю, КАК это реализовать, а высказал идею. Автор просил ДП, вот ему ДП.

Comment: @Zealint меня слово "проще" удивило, по сложности реализации оно будет явно сложнее + понимать надо что делаешь.